# Sys can't boot, recovery broken, adb disabled, zero ideas [Oneplus 5T]

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, fastboot

I tried to update from crdroid 7 (Android 11) to 8 (android 12) with a clean flash (no format data though) and now my situation is the following:

- System is stuck on boot animation
- in fastboot, my device is not recognized, `adb devices`  shows nothing, and `fastboot flash` waits for devices. I tried reinstalling adb and drives, but my guess is that system is sorta installed and disabled usb debugging, which is off by default. I also tried from another pc, device is not found by it.
- twrp is broken, it remains stuck on the twrp logo. Every 5 minutes or the screen flashes black.
- I uninstalled magisk before flashing anything.
- The devices is not encrypted, I removed the password before starting the process

Now, the only hope: the devices is recognized in recovery mode by the pc, even though windows does not mount the storage. Here is what I tried:

- `adb root` says `adbd is already running as root`, but I'm unable to access the root in the adb shell.
- I tried `adb pull \data\media\` but it fails to copy: `open failed: Required key not available`.
- `adb sideload` the recovery or a rom or magisk ends in `error: closed`
- `adb pull /system/build.prop` ends in `remote object '/system/build.prop' does not exist`

So I have not idea how to get the required key to pull the data or enable the usb debugging through adb (so I could reflash the recovery). I have zero clues on how to recover the data and/or the phone so here I am. (I also have to head out from home so I won't be able to reply today)

Comment: Even if the phone has no password it can still be encrypted. Modern Android devices are always encrypted no matter what you do. Your device is from 207 initial with Android 7.1 i am not sure if default encryption was enabled on devices at that time. `Required key not available` also indicates that your user data can not be accessed be cause the default encryption is active but the necessary decryption key is gone or not accessible (assuming you have a recovery that supports user data decryption).

Comment: 1. fastboot is unrelated to adb and doesn't require usb-debugging 2. TWRP provides a [set of terminal commands](https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html) (I would start with *'adb pull /tmp/recovery.log'*)